# Adding ng-app to ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 page "breaks"

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

The short and skinny: I have an app that I am working on and I would love to use angular. Problem is, when I add ng-app="app" to the html tag on my _Layout page, it breaks my Login page (which is the first page a user will come across). When I plug in my credentials and press the log in button, nothing happens. As soon as I remove the ng-app="app" directive, the log in works. Below is some code:

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title>App</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="sidebar" class="container-fluid">
        <div id="sidebar" ui-view="sidebar" class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>
                <li><a asp-controller="AppStuff" asp-action="Get">AppStuff</a>
                <li><a asp-controller="MoreStuff" asp-action="Get">MoreStuff</a></li>

                @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    <li><a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout">Logout</a></li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" ui-view="navbar">
                <div>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                        <li><button id="sidebarToggle" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></button></li>
                    </ul>
                    <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">App</a>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </nav>

        <div id="content" ui-view="content" class="container-fluid">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
                <h4 class="text-center text-info">&copy; App 2016</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/app/app.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/site.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js (compiled from TypeScript):**

```
var app;
(function (app) {
    'use strict';
    config.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider'];
    function config($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            rewriteLinks: false,
            requireBase: false
        });
    }
    run.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$log'];
    function run($rootScope, $log) {
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
            $log.error("State change error:");
            $log.error(toState);
            $log.error(toParams);
            $log.error(fromState);
            $log.error(fromParams);
            $log.error(error);
        });
        $rootScope.$on('$stateNotFound', function (event, unfoundState, fromState, fromParams) {
            console.log(event);
            console.log(unfoundState);
            console.log(fromState);
            console.log(fromParams);
        });
    }
    angular
        .module('app', ['ui.router'])
        .config(config)
        .run(run);
})(app || (app = {}));
```

**Login.cshtml**

```
@model App.ViewModels.LoginViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <h3 class="page-header">Please log in:</h3>
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.ModelOnly"></div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Username"></label>
                <input asp-for="Username" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Username" class="text-warning"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Password"></label>
                <input type="password" asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-warning"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**AccountController.cs:**

```
namespace App.Controllers
{
    [Route("Account")]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private SignInManager<User> _signInManager;

        public AccountController(SignInManager<User> signInManager)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }

        [Route("Login")]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Route("Login")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel vm, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var signedInResult = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(vm.Username, vm.Password,
                    true, false);

                if (signedInResult.Succeeded)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }                   
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username or password is incorrect.");
                }
            }            

            return View();
        }

        public async Task<ActionResult> Logout()
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: When setting a breakpoint on the Login POST, it does not get hit when ng-app is up but it does (obviously) when ng-app is gone.

EDIT2: To answer some of the comments below and add another symptom:
1.) It doesn't work whether html5mode is enabled or disabled.
2.) I've tested in all browsers. No console errors, nothing.

When I remove the ="app", I get page validation from the asp validation. When I add it, no more page validation. Has me thinking this may be an asp.net and/or mvc thing. Any thoughts on this new "development"?

EDIT3: Seems to be an issue with my Login method, probably routing. I removed ng-app and completed log in, then added it back in and successfully logged out. So it seems that my controller can be hit successfully with angular "initialized".

Comment: Is anything written to the console (browser developer tools)?

Comment: Nothing. I'm getting no JavaScript errors, no server-side exceptions.

Comment: It's probably that `html5mode` - is the URL changing when the submit button is clicked?

Comment: @tymeJV: I commented out everything in app.js except for registering the module and ran it, resulting in the same issue I've posted about. I will give it another go this evening when I get some coding time to double-check.

Comment: What browser do you use? Can you test it in different one? One more: what if use data-ng-app instead?

Comment: @vzayko: I've develop in Firefox, but I tested the issue in Chrome as well.